# How do I secure my ASP.NET Core Web API backend?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, keycloak, openid, asp.net-authorization, duende

Trying to develop a backend for a project of mine and I'd like to implement some sort of authorization to be sure that only my ionic client calls the api backend and a safe way for users to login and signin.

I've tried with some "prebuilt" solution like Duende and Keycloak, but with the first one I'm having trouble while trying to access from a client that's outside the project (my web client is an ionic app) and the second one gives me problem over some SSL stuff that I wasn't able to solve after a full night of research and trials (.NET Core wants an https issuer but keycloak normally doesn't start as one, if I do the certificate it says it's invalid and if I disable the need for the https in the option of .NET Core `program.cs` it ignores it)...

I'm a bit desperate because I can't wrap my head around it and I can only find old tutorials...

Comment: You need to add some code showing what you did so far, please have a read on the help center as to [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Besides, you can read [ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more.